# How to limit flask/Javascript to access a URL one at a time

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, request

So I currently have in frontend an ajax request that sends every 7 seconds a request to a specific URL. Because it's online sometimes it takes longer to process the function and it's ending up accepting more and more requests without even accepting the first one and I am ending up with 4 ping requests. I would like to know if there is a way to accept one at a time so if the ajax request sends a request and if the one before the request is still pinging then the backend will reject it or maybe there is a way to do in frontend.

```
setInterval(() => {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "site/example",
.....
}, 7000);
```

so in this example the backend will reject requests for `site/example`. The frontend will not send the ajax request. until the initial request didn't get a return ones it did. It will do the same thing for the next request and so on...

Comment: It would be better (and probably easier) to limit simultaneous requests on the frontend rather than on the backend - what if several clients want to access the endpoint simultaneously?

Comment: Ok, and how can I do that? I changed the question according to what you are saying

Comment: While what you are asking for is technically possible, it goes against how the web is designed to work.  Could you explain more about your use case and why you want this as well? That might help us solve the more important issue.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner My problem is that it checks every x seconds a URL and if it returns a file it will go the file's URL and sometimes it loads like 4 requests that were pinging and then accepting them all at ones

Comment: Why is multiple requests all at once a bad thing? Generally, you build web severs to handle exactly this case. The bug is usually when a web server can't handle as many requests as needed, not too many. However, there are [throttling utilities](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=rate%20limitt) that will prevent a client from making too many requests if that is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can think of using a hack using a global flag variable. Initially set a variable `flag` as true.Just before creating ajax request, check the `flag` as true or not. If true send the request, and change the `flag` to false, else don't send request (wait for next 7 second). On success ( and failure callback )of ajax request, change the `flag` to true, so that we can initiate next connection after 7 second. This procedure will help in having a single connection request at a time